# Enable ACK/NAK handshaking for UART serial port communication

Tags: linux, serial-port

A barcode reader that has a UART male interface is connected through a serial port on my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop. From the proprietary readme doc, I came to know that I would have to enable the ACK/NAK handshaking in order to get an ACK or a NAK from the device for the commands that I send. I am not sure how to enable those using C serial port programming in Linux environment.

Can someone throw some light on this?

**UPDATE:**

Did the following to enable software handshaking - 

`system ("stty ixon -ixoff -F /dev/tty");

bzero (shcmd, 64);

sprintf (shcmd, "stty ixon -ixoff -F %s", UART_DEVICE);

system (shcmd);`

Set the speed - 

`system("stty speed 9600");

bzero (shcmd, 64);

sprintf (shcmd, "stty speed 9600 -F %s", UART_DEVICE);

system (shcmd);`

Wrote a command - 

`unsigned char req_rev[6] = {0x05,0xA3,0x04,0x00,0xFF,0x55};

n = write(fd, req_rev, 6);`

Read from the device - 

`int n = read(fd, result, 254);`

But I got "EGAIN" every time while reading. Any idea why I get that?

Answer (score 1):

ACK/NACK does not exist. What exists is XON/XOFF. From here :

- The doc use ACK/NACK for XON/XOFF, and your problem is "how to set XON/XOFF on my serial port".
- The doc is right, and the first thing you should do is enable the ACK/NACK mechanism in your device by sending an appropriate command. To get help you will need to explore the doc or provide more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me proceed in that direction.